# Task manager remove app event listener

Tags: android

I removed application from task manager, How to catch event in app on remove app from task manager.I want stop media player on remove application from task manager.

Answer (score 1):

Android does not have a "task manager". Hence, it is unclear whether you mean swiping a task off of the recent-tasks list, or if you are referring to using some device-specific or third-party task manager.

Regardless, there is no event when your task is removed. Your process is simply terminated.

Answer (score 0):

When you destroy your app from swiping away, the `onDestroy()` method is called, so you can then release all the resources you need, for example:

Stop a sound if it's playing when you kill the app.

```
@Override
publi void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
     if (ringing != null) {

               if (ringing.isPlaying() || ringing.isLooping()) {

                      ringing.stop();
                      ringing.reset();
                      ringing.release();
                      ringing = null;

                }

    } else {
        ringing = null;
        return;
    }

}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: onDestroy method not called.